# Replace a value in a multidimensional array given the indexes of value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have an array that contains the location of a value in a very large multidimensional array. I need to take this location and replace the value at the location with another value. I have found numerous articles about returning the value of a position using such an array of indexes by writing a recursive function. However, this won't work because I can't slice up the large array, I need to replace just that one value.

The location would look something like:

```
array(1,5,3,4,6);
```

The code I had to find a value is the following:

```
function replace_value($indexes, $array, $replacement){
    if(count($indexes) > 1)
        return replace_value(array_slice($indexes, 1), $array[$indexes[0]], $replacement);
    else
        return $array[$indexes[0]];
    }
}
```

How would I modify this to instead of recursively cutting down an array until the value is found I can simply modify a part of a large array? Is there a way to build

```
array(1,5,3,4,6);
```

Into

```
$array[1][5][3][4][6];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could modify your function like this:

```
function replace_value($indexes, &$array, $replacement){
    if(count($indexes) > 1) {
        return replace_value(array_slice($indexes, 1), $array[$indexes[0]], $replacement);
    } else {
        return $array[$indexes[0]] = $replacement;
    }
}
```

Make sure your write `&$array` in the function definition, not `$array`  This will pass in the actual array, so that you can modify it in place.  Otherwise you would just be passing in a copy.

Comment: Works like a charm except you have an extra } at the end of the else statement

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you trust the contents of the variable containing your array indices, this is a completely valid use of `eval`:

```
$keys = array(1,5,3,4,6);

$keys = "[" . join($keys, "][") . "]";

$value = "what";

eval("\$array$keys = '$value';"); # $array[1][5][3][4][6] = 'what';
```

Comment: +1 I agree(it makes for simple, effective, clear code), although I would var_export() $value

Comment: "Assuming you trust the contents of the variable containing your array indices" ... well that's the whole problem with `eval` isn't it?

Comment: @Madbreaks Are you serious? It's idiot-proof. You either trust it or you don't, and if you *don't know* you're a bad programmer.

Comment: Ah, so what you're saying is, `eval` is safe! Right. See, the fact that *I* know my data is safe is one thing.  What if your environment changes?  Your development team?  Etc.  There's a reason that when you google "eval is evil" you'll find 10,000,000 page hits.  If you think `eval` is idiot-proof, well, I'd say go easy throwing around "idiot".  You are wrong.

Comment: @Madbreaks Eval is neither safe or unsafe, the *data you are feeding it* is. You are scanning a nested array, building up a non-nested array of **numeric** indices. If your team changes and the new guys can somehow introduce a code-injection vulnerability while doing this, you are at fault for hiring *staggeringly* bad programmers. "Eval-is-evil" has 10,000,000 page hits because of cargo-cult programmers who parrot catchy phrases without first *thinking* about the reasoning behind them.

Comment: safe can mean you have other code ensuring it. i feel he went far enough mentioning it. there's plenty of other code dangers people will run into implementing non eval containing code snippets from the interwebs if they arent responsible for their own accord.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without using eval. Go through each key and reduce the array as you go. The `$ref` variable below is a reference to the original array so changing it will change the original.

```
$keys = array(1,5,3,4,6);
$array[1][5][3][4][6] = 'foo';
$ref = &$array;

foreach( $keys as $key ) {
    $ref = &$ref[ $key ];
}

$ref = 'bar';

echo $array[1][5][3][4][6];  // 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested. I tend to shy away from using references because I think they're particularly confusing, and they leave remnant reference in your code that can cause difficult to find bugs.

```
$keys = array(1,5,3,4,6);
$path = 'new leaf value';
foreach (array_reverse($keys) as $key) {
    $path = array($key => $path);
}

$modified = array_replace_recursive($origionalArray, $path);
```